# Importing in python, how many ways can it be done?

Tags: python, import

I was reading about imports in python and came across this [effbot article](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) about imports.

> Python provides at least three different ways to import modules. You can use the `import` statement, the `from` statement, or the builtin `__import__` function. (There are more contrived ways to do this too, but that’s outside the scope for this small note.)

I am wondering if anyone is able to point out some or all of the contrived ways that this can be done? The only other way to achieve an import that I can think of is

`exec("import os")` and all the possible contrived methods of creating the string inside the `exec` statement.

Comment: I'm just curious. I find that following up on these kinds of things that I come across is a more interesting (and longer-lasting) way of getting to know the finer details of the language I'm using than only reading docs about, say, the builtin module. And I'm a fan of the ioccc so that probably explains a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this sufficiently contrived?

```
os = getattr(__builtins__, "".join(chr(ord(x) - 1) for x in  "``jnqpsu``"))("os")
```

Comment: Awesome. Leaving the ("os") off the end effectively renames the import function to any other name. Very interesting stuff.

Comment: @thedawnrider: Yes, but giving new names to existing functions is trivial in Python.

Comment: To add to this, you can also obfuscate __builtins__ by doing locals()["".join(chr(ord(x) - 1) for x in "``cvjmujot``")]